# Creating an executable python script, with OS commands, to start Blender and run another script

Tags: python

I need a little help creating an executable python OS command for Blender (Windows and Mac). 
I am setting up a stand-alone blender package for a client to use. I have a python script that imports some data and I want to create an executable python script that runs OS commands to run Blender, run the python script and define the data directories.

This is a generic version of the Windows command I normally run to import the data, using the stand-alone version of Blender:

```
"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Package\system\blender\blender.exe" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Package\system\version_data\CurrentVersion.blend" -P "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Package\system\version_data\BlenderScript.py" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Package\input_data\\" -y
```

From my research I have worked out that I need to:

1. import os
2. make the directories in the command relative
3. create an executable python file

My python experience is limited, but I believe it may be something like this:

```
import os

pythonDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(RunThisApp.exe))  # get the current dir of this file (which would be: C:\Users\username\Desktop\Package\)

os.path.join(pathDirectory, "//system\blender\blender.exe" "//system\version_data\CurrentVersion.blend" -P "//system\version_data\BlenderScript.py" "//input_data\\" -y)
```

However I had a look at this post and was a little fuzzy as to the best way to do this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Then I could possibly use PyInstaller to create the python executable files. Which seems to be the simplest method suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

[http://www.pyinstaller.org/](http://www.pyinstaller.org/%20%22PyInstaller)

Am I close to the correct result here? I am guessing my syntax is off. I need to make sure it works for both Windows and Mac.

It should also be noted that the separate python script I run to import data  into blender (which I have been using and updating for a couple of years), refers to OS arguments to get the desired path of data to import, so I need to make sure that I maintain that connection. Here is an example:

```
IMPORT_DATA_FILENAME = sys.argv[4]+'data.txt'
```

Any advice or input would be greatly appreciated.
Chris Lee

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, this seems like more of a Python question than a Blender one. I think this would be better suited to one of the programming focused StackExchanges.

Comment: You may be correct. I will do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general Python question, not a Blender-specific one.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can close the question?
Should I delete it, or wait?

Comment: I posted the question over here instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053517/creating-an-executable-python-script-with-os-commands-to-start-blender-and-run